# Vega chart interactive crossfilter populate other charts on click of first

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am referring to the below example of vega chart.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_layered_crossfilter.html

I want to have the functionality that when **distance bar** of the chart is clicked then **delay and time** gets loaded with respect to the value of distance.

Comment: If you want other people to be able to see your chart, you need to click *Share* then *Copy Link To Clipboard*, then paste the URL in the question.

Comment: @jakevdp You can check the url now. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `interval` selection to a `single` selection ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICAM2FksEfgCYA1lJnylxttuSY0oHEm0Q4Hg5h+6KqBIAC+EUqY2kiyEM6uaADaoFBIglAMgmpBGGw6EAAUIQwIlCFwAJSKIEgQ+pg0CH5hALpK2nA4cGr+UGyCpfKoSSo0EOqyUH5KynDZAJ41jc0grWFKEN1Q-otw2smgvoJwUI1y-kzaDBAw-pgL3foQNLJkJzVwU2zKr2T1IxAAA81pEQMhtDZ9ExvJ9vr83v4QZoQMYaPNlP5Ot1euh+oMEPINiAmK9-MggaS4mgrAAGMFLFFIMhkToUUJ4-KydzE-EufzEdIMXIAYmU4vCkVA0Vi8RcCEOqJogkCBxRx1O52GJOut0l7XB3ih6BhByUX36CLISP8aIxWK6PXcnIJRKUVPJSEprwBdIZ-mZrL4HJA-QY3MlbQiQA)):

The only difference in the chart at that link is that I changed this:

```
"selection": {
  "brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
},
```

to this:

```
"selection": {
  "brush": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["x"]}
},
```

And now you can select single bars by clicking.